# Flutter share_plus is not working and getting error

Tags: flutter, plugins, share

I want to share text / url in my app and I'm using [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) plugin for this.

```
        IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
            onPressed: (){
              Share.share("Testing Share function");
            }
        ),
```

And I'm getting error:

```
E/flutter (21225): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/share)
E/flutter (21225): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165:7)
E/flutter (21225): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21225):
```

How to fix this?